# Creating multiple records with the same information but different foreign key

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I have a **Microsoft Access** database and have a `Employees` and `TicketsBooked` tables where TicketsBooked stores the tickets booked for Employees.

I am having difficulties designing a form to **create the same ticket** for multiple employees at the same time.

I tried making a simple form but the problem is that I have to fill the same ticket information multiple times with only the `EmployeeID` being different.

Comment: If so much data is repeated, maybe need different data structure: Employees, Trips, Tickets - Tickets would be junction table to associate Employees with Trips. Then build form/subform arrangement. Otherwise, use code to repeat the trip info in TicketsBooked. One way is to set control's DefaultValue property then this value will carry forward to subsequent records until user enters different value. Use each control's AfterUpdate event. This is a fairly common topic.

Comment: I took your idea of using code to repeat the most recent TicketsBooked and it worked just as I wanted it to so thank you! I used this video to help me Implement the solution if anyone is facing the same problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2PI6w_J95Y&ab_channel=ComputerLearningZone